# SQL Union All to display old data with new data?

Tags: sql, ms-access, union

In MS Access,  I have some reports that use some queries, to show data, within a date range. The queries use aliases, if, sum, and avg functions, and join multiple tables to get its data.

I'd like to know if i could use a UNION ALL, with a table that has all the needed fields, to display this new data from this table, along with the older data, if someone selects a range that spans the new and the old.

Here's an example "old" query:

```
SELECT tblAssessment.fldValid, tblATraining.fldTID, tblATraining.fldTCrsID, 
tblCourses.fldCrsName, [fldCrsHrs]/8 AS Days, tblATraining.fldTLocAbr, 
tblDistrict.fldDistAbr, tblRegion.fldRegName, tblATraining.fldTDateStart, 
tblATraining.fldTDateEnd, tblATraining.fldTEnrolled, tblATraining.fldTPID, 
tblPersonnel.fldPName, tblAssessment.fldTrngSID, tblAssessment.Q1, 
IIf([fldValid]=True,IIf([Q1]>0,1,0),0) AS Q1Valid, tblAssessment.Q2, 
IIf([fldValid]=True,IIf([Q2]>0,1,0),0) AS Q2Valid, tblAssessment.Q3, 
IIf([fldValid]=True,IIf([Q3]>0,1,0),0) AS Q3Valid, tblAssessment.Q4, 
IIf([fldValid]=True,IIf([Q4]>0,1,0),0) AS Q4Valid, tblAssessment.Q5, 
IIf([fldValid]=True,IIf([Q5]>0,1,0),0) AS Q5Valid, tblAssessment.Q6, 
IIf([fldValid]=True,IIf([Q6]>0,1,0),0) AS Q6Valid, tblAssessment.Q7, 
IIf([fldValid]=True,IIf([Q7]>0,1,0),0) AS Q7Valid, tblAssessment.Q8, 
tblAssessment.Q9, 
IIf([fldValid]=True,IIf([Q9]>0,1,0),0) AS Q9Valid, tblAssessment.Q10, 
IIf([fldValid]=True,IIf([Q10]>0,1,0),0) AS Q10Valid, tblAssessment.Q11, 
IIf([fldValid]=True,IIf([Q11]>0,1,0),0) AS Q11Valid, tblAssessment.Q12, 
IIf([fldValid]=True,IIf([Q12]>0,1,0),0) AS Q12Valid, tblAssessment.Q13, 
tblAssessment.Q14, 
IIf([fldValid]=True,IIf([Q14]>0,1,0),0) AS Q14Valid, tblAssessment.Q15, 
IIf([fldValid]=True,IIf([Q15]>0,1,0),0) AS Q15Valid, tblAssessment.Q16, 
IIf([fldValid]=True,IIf([Q16]>0,1,0),0) AS Q16Valid, tblAssessment.Q17, 
IIf([fldValid]=True,IIf([Q17]>0,1,0),0) AS Q17Valid, tblAssessment.Q18, 
IIf([fldValid]=True,IIf([Q18]>0,1,0),0) AS Q18Valid, tblAssessment.Q19, 
IIf([fldValid]=True,IIf([Q19]>0,1,0),0) AS Q19Valid, tblAssessment.Q20, 
tblAssessment.Q21, 
IIf([fldValid]=True,IIf([Q21]>0,1,0),0) AS Q21Valid, tblAssessment.Q22, 
IIf([fldValid]=True,IIf([Q22]>0,1,0),0) AS Q22Valid, tblAssessment.Q23, 
IIf([fldValid]=True,IIf([Q23]>0,1,0),0) AS Q23Valid, tblAssessment.Q24, 
IIf([fldValid]=True,IIf([Q24]>0,1,0),0) AS Q24Valid, tblAssessment.Q25, 
IIf([fldValid]=True,IIf([Q25]>0,1,0),0) AS Q25Valid, tblAssessment.Q26, 
IIf([fldValid]=True,IIf([Q26]>0,1,0),0) AS Q26Valid, tblAssessment.Q27, 
IIf([fldValid]=True,IIf([Q27]>0,1,0),0) AS Q27Valid, tblAssessment.Q28, 
IIf([fldValid]=True,IIf([Q28]>0,1,0),0) AS Q28Valid, tblAssessment.Q29, 
tblAssessment.Q30, 
tblAssessment.Q31, tblAssessment.Q32
FROM ((tblDistrict 
       LEFT JOIN tblRegion ON tblDistrict.fldDRegID = tblRegion.fldRegID) 
       RIGHT JOIN (((tblATraining 
                     LEFT JOIN tblCourses ON tblATraining.fldTCrsID = tblCourses.fldCrsID) 
                   LEFT JOIN tblPersonnel ON tblATraining.fldTPID = tblPersonnel.fldPID) 
                  LEFT JOIN tblLocations ON tblATraining.fldTLocAbr = tblLocations.fldLID) ON tblDistrict.fldDistAbr = tblATraining.fldTDistAbr) 
     LEFT JOIN tblAssessment ON tblATraining.fldTID = tblAssessment.fldTrngCID
WHERE (((tblAssessment.fldValid)=True) 
        AND ((tblATraining.fldTCrsID) Like [forms]![fdlgRptCriteria].[selCrsCd]) 
        AND ((tblATraining.fldTDateStart) Between [forms]![fdlgRptCriteria].[seldate1] And [forms]![fdlgRptCriteria].[seldate2]) 
        AND ((tblAssessment.fldTrngSID) Is Not Null));
```

Comment: Try using a code block - it'll retain your formatting.

Comment: I tried my best to format it into something somewhat readable. I'm baffled by the explicitness of the join order (whether Access will even honor the exact way you specify or not is up for debate), and all the parentheses in the WHERE clause, but that's ok.

Comment: @lc: ACE/Jet *forces* you to be explicit about a JOIN order by requiring each join (except the last) to be in parentheses. But you are correct that the JOIN order is not guaranteed in that optimizer can change the order if it sees fit to do so (so that's another way in which ACE/Jet is non-compliant with Standard SQL).

Comment: Thanks everyone for all the input on this very old question! Sorry I did't say thanks 7 years ago!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but you might consider creating a new querydef for the union.

(You'll need to use the SQL design window last time I checked.)

It would be approximately:

```
    SELECT
    tblATraining.fldTID,
    tblATraining.fldTCrsID,
    tblATraining.fldTLocAbr,
    tblATraining.fldTDateStart,
    tblATraining.fldTDateStart,
    tblATraining.fldTDateEnd,
    tblATraining.fldTEnrolled,
    tblATraining.fldTPID

    UNION ALL

    tblATrainingArchive.fldTID,
    tblATrainingArchive.fldTCrsID,
    tblATrainingArchive.fldTLocAbr,
    tblATrainingArchive.fldTDateStart,
    tblATrainingArchive.fldTDateStart,
    tblATrainingArchive.fldTDateEnd,
    tblATrainingArchive.fldTEnrolled,
    tblATrainingArchive.fldTPID
```

and name it something like tblATrainingUnion.

Then just plug that into your existing query wherever you have tblATraining.

Note: Many people also tend to create an archive table sooner than it really makes sense - you might consider just leaving it all in the main table, and make the split when you can actually measure the difference. (You may already have reached that point and done that; and it can make more sense with Access than with say SQL Server.)

Comment: Yes and I would try to set it up so that use of the union is limited to as-needed.  Unions are notoriously slooow with large recordsets.

Comment: "you might consider creating a new querydef for the union... You'll need to use the SQL design window last time I checked" -- actually, querydef was a DAO object last time I checked, therefore you'd need to use DAO :) FWIW DAO's querydef maps to a ACE/Jet's VIEW or PROCEDURE i.e. granularity between the two is lost with DAO.

Comment: @le dorfier: you don't need to qualify the columns using the table name because there is only one table in scope... well, there will be when you actually add the line 'FROM tblATraining' :) Ditto tblATrainingArchive.

Comment: Querydefs aren't an artifact of the API; they are (or at least used to be) the stored queries in access. They needed a new word - it's neither a View nor a Stored Procedure.

Comment: I was wondering if i could union all the query, even though it has the WHERE criteria, accepting a date range from a form

Comment: You can use the query to design a form. Then, whether you specify the WHERE criteria beforehand (with for instance "WHERE fldTDateStart >= ? AND fldTDateStart < ?" and the question marks will require you to replace them with dates; or you build the WHERE clause as part of the form design, either will get you what you need.

Comment: @onedaywhen: The query designer creates a saved QueryDef, just as DAO does. There's no difference in the result, just in the method used to accomplish it, i.e., one is interactive with high-level user interface tools that write the SQL for you, and the other is code-based. Me, well, I've created QueryDefs in code about, hmm, 10 times since I started using Access on a daily basis back in 1996. And I probably used the QBE to write the base SQL used in the DAO commands to do it. It's not that I don't know how, it's that I don't see why I should use code for something that is so easy without it.

Comment: @David W. Fenton and @le dorfier: I create a VIEW via SQL DDL CREATE VIEW and subsequently retrieve the details from INFORMATION SCHEMA via OLE DB VIEWS Rowset. Ditto using CREATE PROCEDURE and the PROCEDURES Rowset. The engine sees the granularity between the VIEW and PROCEDURE but the Access UI and DAO do not. You need to get some new tools so you can too ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Access supports `UNION ALL`. A simple example would be:

```
select foo from OldData
union all
select foo from NewData
```

Answer (score 1):

I would emphasize @le dorfier's comment about archiving. Most Access applications with a Jet data store don't need data to be archived. A client of mine runs a billing system for 6 parking garages that I built for her back in 1997-98 (it's been upgraded, extended and revised extensively since then). It includes data for that entire period (200-300 invoices for each month for each garage) and it works just as fast now as it did back then. Part of that is the increase in the performance of PCs (i.e., with the same amount of data and 1997-era PCs, it would probably be very slow), but it still works just fine.

If speed started to be an issue, we'd probably move the back end to SQL Server Express. The last thing we'd contemplate would be archiving the data.

Another client of mine insisted on archiving their inactive data, and then I had to reprogram the ADD NEW RECORD function to check against the archive (because of the requirements of the app, it's crucial that the same person not have a new record created, but instead have it retrieved from the archive). This vastly slowed down the process of adding new records. Now I'm trying to convince them to "de-archive" their data, because it hasn't actually helped them in any way and has made things work more slowly during daily operations.

Answer (score 0):

Two comments not related to your question.

1) What's the purpose of the Q1 to Q32 fields? I'm thinking that maybe those could be somehow redesigned and/or normalized.

2) I see no reason to use naming standards on object names.  Such as tbl, fld, frm, qry and so forth.   You pretty much know what kind of an object they are by the context in the code.  If in the various database container windows those are pretty obvious as well.

That said I do somewhat use the variable naming conventions in my VBA code just to help keep those clear.

See [Tony's Object Naming Conventions](http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/tonysobjectnamingconventions.htm) and [Tony's Table and Field Naming Conventions](http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/tablefieldnaming.htm) for more details.

I quite expect some folks to strenuously disagree with my second comment and to thumbs down my posting.

Comment: About tbl, fld, frm, qry, I could get along without all of them except tbl and qry, and that's because Access presents tabledefs and querydefs as a single namespace, and I need to be able to distinguish the two. That said, during major overhauls of existing apps that I didn't create, I'll often create a query called tblMyTable that is the replacement for the real MyTable. It's a query, but it is named like it's a table, but this is an entirely temporary thing, for the period in which I'm reworking UI and am not able to restructure the back end to meed the new standards.